# How can my Firebase rules access different shards?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Assuming the following structure:

```
firebase
- database
  - shard 1
  - shard 2
  - shard 3
```

Shard 1 has `users/byId/$ids`. I want to write a rule for shard 3 that will look into `shard 1/users/byId` to see if a user's ID exists.

Is it possible for a rule to look into a different shard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem possible:

> **Security**
>
> Each database instance has its own set of security rules. Sharded
> databases can handle different structures which means you can apply
> different rules based on that database's purpose. You can manage and
> test each database's rule set in the console. ***It's important to note
> that databases are completely independent. This means you cannot
> access another database's data in rules evaluation.***

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/11/easier-scaling-with-multi-database.html